# jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end in windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, jq

I am trying to read credentials from assume role like `AcccessKeyID` and store in a variable but getting error:
My code and error is:

```
jq -r '".Credentials.AccessKeyId"' mysession.json | awk '"{print "set","AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="$0}"' > variables
```

> jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
> '".Credentials.AccessKeyId"'
> jq: 1 compile error
> awk: '"{print
> awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression

Please suggest me how to achieve this activity in **windows CMD** .I have installed jq and awk in windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn role_arn --role-session-name session_name > mysession.json


$ak = jq -r ".Credentials.AccessKeyId" mysession.json
$sk = jq -r ".Credentials.SecretAccessKey" mysession.json
$tk = jq -r ".Credentials.SessionToken" mysession.json

Write-Host "Acccess Key ID:" $ak
Write-Host "Secret Acccess Key:" $sk
Write-Host "Session Token:" $tk
```

**Powershell**

```
$source_profile = "default"
$region = "ap-southeast-2"
$role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::account_id:role/role-test"
$target_profile = "test"
$target_profile_path =  "$HOME\.aws\credentials"
$session_name = "test"

# Assume Role
$Response = (Use-STSRole -Region $region -RoleArn  $role_arn -RoleSessionName $session_name -ProfileName $source_profile).Credentials

# Export Crendentail as environment variable
$env:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$Response.AccessKeyId
$env:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$Response.SecretAccessKey
$env:AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$Response.SessionToken

# Create Profile with Credentials
Set-AWSCredential -StoreAs $target_profile -ProfileLocation $target_profile_path -AccessKey $Response.AccessKeyId -SecretKey $Response.SecretAccessKey -SessionToken $Response.SessionToken

# Print expiration time
Write-Host("Credentials will expire at: " + $Response.Expiration)
```

[AWS Assume Role Script](https://ripon-banik.medium.com/aws-assume-role-script-4e7d3b548f20)

[How can I parse an assumed role's credentials in powershell and set them as a variable in a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52671797/2246345)

Comment: I am getting error "'$ak' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. " when giving $ak = jq -r ".Credentials.AccessKeyId" mysession.json in cmd of Windows.

Comment: @AshishJoshi are you able to run `jq -r .Credentials.AccessKeyId mysession.json` this should give the necessary output similary you can chain rest of the keys from json file and set the env vars.

Answer (score 0):

On the jq site it mentions [syntax adjustments for Windows](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq):

> "when using the Windows command shell (cmd.exe) it's best to use
> double quotes around your jq program when given on the command-line
> (instead of the -f program-file option), but then double-quotes in the
> jq program need backslash escaping."

So, instead of

```
jq -r '".Credentials.AccessKeyId"' mysession.json
```

You'll need to escape double quotes, then change single quotes to double.

```
jq -r "\".Credentials.AccessKeyId\"" mysession.json
```