# AWS sts assume role with a powershell script

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli

I am looking for a way to assume a role in CLI using one command in a powershell script.

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789123:role/myAwesomeRole --role-session-name test
```

When I run the above I will get an output like below.

```
{
"Credentials": {
    "AccessKeyId": "someAccessKeyId",
    "SecretAccessKey": "someSecretAccessKey",
    "SessionToken": "someSessionToken",
    "Expiration": "2020-08-04T06:52:13+00:00"
},
"AssumedRoleUser": {
    "AssumedRoleId": "idOfTheAssummedRole",
    "Arn": "theARNOfTheRoleIWantToAssume"
    }
}
```

I have been looking for a way to take the output and automatically assume the role. I have only been able to find thing in bash. I have seen something along  the lines of this:

```
export $(printf "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=%s AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=%s AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=%s" \
$(aws sts assume-role \
--role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/MyAssumedRole \
--role-session-name MySessionName \
--query "Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]" \
--output text))
```

If anyone can help me out it would be great.

Comment: Does it have to be one line? Why? Does it have to be a batch file?

Comment: Multiple lines should work. It needs to be a batch file because our CI/CD agent runs on a Windows machine. When it runs the CI/CD it runs it as a AWS CLI running in Windows command line.

Comment: Could it be Powershell for example? Batch scripting is really trivial & it would be super hard - yet not impossible - to parse the resulting JSON. Or even if it was in pure text.

Comment: I can try it in powershell. I need to see if Teamcity can run the CLI commands in powershell. Powershell should work if I can figure out a script for that.

Comment: If so, update the question + tags & let me know and I can probably come up with something. Teamcity 100% can run Powershell but just doublecheck :)

Comment: Ok great. I updated the tags. Thank you. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Now in that case... does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52671797/4800344

Comment: Ok I got it to work locally. An idea if there is a way to run this without saving the credentials file?

Comment: Store it in a variable on the fly - 'powershell save output as variable' should yield what you need :)